# rails simple calendar events per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using the rails simple calendar gem to render a calendar. On mobile I am trying to display a list of events below the calendar for the day that is clicked. I am having a hard time getting the events to be selected correctly though based on the datefilter param that is passed through.

Here is the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location = '/scheduleevents?datefilter=<%= day %>'"
```

Here is the controller index action:

```
date = Date.parse(params[:datefilter]) if params[:datefilter].present?
 
@scheduleevents = Scheduleevent.where(
       start_time: Time.now.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week..Time.now.end_of_month.end_of_week
     )
@scheduleeventsday =   @scheduleevents.where("start_time < date && end_time > date") if params[:datefilter].present?
```

I am getting a syntax error on the date compare. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You cannot run ruby code inside of sql statements. Try `@scheduleevents.where(date: start_time..end_time)`

Comment: Also, using window.location is really not necessary, just use a `link_to` and style your link as a button if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! When I do @scheduleeventsday = Scheduleevent.where(date: start_time..end_time) I get an error that there is an undefined local variable start_time

Comment: `@scheduleevents.where('date between start_time and end_time)`

Comment: Thanks. So doing @scheduleevents.where('date between start_time and end_time') gives me the error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "date" does not exist.

Comment: ok, `@scheduleevents.where('? between start_time and end_time', date)`

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer. That runs without error but I am still not getting the results I need. Start_time end_time are being stored like this: "2022-08-24 10:00:00" I am passing the datefilter through like this "2022-08-24". So based on that I am not getting any results which I am guessing because it is not between 10:00AM and 10:00PM. What is the best way to only compare the day portion (222-08-24) of start_time end_time?

Comment: Try `start_time::date`